# Set pre-installation ownership and permissions

Tags: magento2, installation

I'm developer, not system administrator, and I'm trying out to configure Magento environment production like.

I'm stuck in 
'Set ownership and permissions for two users'
'Step 5: Set ownership and permissions for the shared group'

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

So I have Ubuntu on my laptop, apache2, php, mysql.

created Magento install dir from 'sudo' in /var/www/html/magento2

next steps would be

```
switch to, the Magento file system owner.
Enter the following commands in the order shown:

cd /var/www/html/magento2/
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
sudo chown -R :www-data .
chmod u+x bin/magento

find: ‘var’: No such file or directory
find: ‘generated’: No such file or directory
find: ‘vendor’: No such file or directory
find: ‘pub/static’: No such file or directory
find: ‘pub/media’: No such file or directory
find: ‘app/etc’: No such file or directory
```

at this point I add some forward slash

```
find /var /generated /vendor /pub/static /pub/media /app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;

...
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/log/alternatives.log.6.gz': Operation not permitted
find: ‘/generated’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/vendor’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/pub/static’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/pub/media’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/app/etc’: No such file or directory
```

So:
on Ubuntu my 'web server group' would be 'www-data'

```
groups magento_user
magento_user : magento_user www-data

ps aux | grep apache
root      1010  0.0  0.3 499316 30644 ?        Ss   14:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1066  0.0  0.2 501648 17684 ?        S    14:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1067  0.0  0.2 501648 17684 ?        S    14:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1068  0.0  0.2 501648 17684 ?        S    14:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1069  0.0  0.2 501648 17684 ?        S    14:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1070  0.0  0.2 501648 17684 ?        S    14:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
magento+ 16295  0.0  0.0  14432  1088 pts/0    S+   14:49   0:00 grep --color=auto apache

groups www-data 
www-data : www-data
```

so despite 'www-data' group I still don't have permission.

```
In the event file system permissions are set improperly and can’t be changed by the Magento file system owner, 
you can enter the command as a user with root privileges:
```

so I did, changed to root

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2/
sudo find /var /generated /vendor /pub/static /pub/media /app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && find /var /generated /vendor /pub/static /pub/media /app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

no complaints about permission, only missing dir structure

```
$ cd ../
/var/www/html$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 10918 ott  1 15:17 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 ott  2 12:30 magento2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root    68 ott  1 17:16 phpinfo.php
```

And if I try next step

Install Magento using Composer

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html

```
magento_user@roman-pc:/var/www/html$ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.2.6)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.2.6): Downloading (connectinDownloading (100%)         
Downloading (100%)         
Downloading (100%)         
In Filesystem.php line 232:

  Could not delete magento2/:  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

My questions are:

- why my folder structure is different
- why magento_user still without permission

If I'm following wrong direction please try to be explicit on how to proceed